# Print output in JSON array-Python

Tags: python, json, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to print the dictionary in JSON format in just one go rather than one by one.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import functools
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode




class ReadParams:


    def __init__(self):

        self.spark_session = (
            SparkSession.builder
            .appName("read parameters")
            .getOrCreate()
        )

        self.input_directory = dbutils.secrets.get(scope="test", key="inpath")
   
    '''
    Reading the schema from csv file
    '''

    def readConfig(self):
            logger.info(f"Reading the Config present in {self.input_directory} ")
            dfConfig = self.spark_session.read.option("multiline","true") \
                           .json(self.input_directory)
            dfConfig=dfConfig.select(explode('a').alias('a'))\
                 .select('a.Type','a.Container','a.Query')
            for f in dfConfig.rdd.toLocalIterator():
                self.Type=f[0]
                self.query=f[1]
                self.container=f[2]           
                self.readFromCosmos(self)
         
    def readFromCosmos(self,*params):
        Endpoint=dbutils.secrets.get(scope="test", key="Endpoint")
        MasterKey = dbutils.secrets.get(scope="test", key="DevKey")
        cosmosDatabaseName = "data_v2"
        cosmosContainerName = self.container
        query=self.query
        cfg = {
  "spark.cosmos.accountEndpoint" : Endpoint,
  "spark.cosmos.accountKey": MasterKey,
  "spark.cosmos.database" : cosmosDatabaseName,
  "spark.cosmos.read.inferSchema.enabled": "true",
  "spark.cosmos.container" : cosmosContainerName,
  "spark.cosmos.read.customQuery":query,
}
        
        logger.info(f"Captured Cosmos Configs {cfg}")
        df=self.spark_session.read.format("cosmos.oltp").options(**cfg).option("spark.cosmos.read.inferSchema.enabled", "true").load()
        df.cache()
        Data={}
        if len(df.head(1)) >0:
           self.Status="Failure"
           Data["Type"] = self.Type
           Data["container"] = self.container

                    
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
   p = ReadData()
   p.readConfig()
```

Current output

**Type** Completeness

**container** ct-data

**Type** Accuracy

**container** trans-data

The expected output in JSON array

```
"Type":["Completeness","Accuracy"],
"container":["ct-data","trans-data"]
```

Moreover, intermittently I am getting the error -`IllegalArgumentException: The config property 'spark.cosmos.read.customquery' is invalid. No config setting with this name exists.`Is it due to the cosmosConnector?

Adding the sample input file

```
{
   "Input":[
      {
         "Type":"Completeness",
         "container":"ct-data",
         "Query":"select * from d"
      },
      {
         "Type":"Accuracy",
         "container":"trans-data",
         "Query":"select * from d where d.id=4"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Are you not showing code? because self.rule is only called but never set so it is unclear how your output is the way that it is.

Comment: Yes,its in the input file I am providing but anyways I have removed that for clarity

Comment: furhter shouldn't `self.Type` and `self.container` be a list that you are appending to instead of assigning a single value to them? this would change `self.Type.append(f[0])` and `self.container.append(f[2])` further you would have to declare each as a list

Comment: Getting error 
AttributeError: 'readFromCosmos' object has no attribute 'Type'

Comment: Hello @Datawriter, it will be helpful if you can share details present in input file. Need source structure for Type and Container.

Comment: Added the input file

Comment: Any pointers on the json array?